# on a button click, copy whats inside entry() and store it to a variable (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two widgets to work with, a text input, and a button, both are created inside a function. What I want to happen is the user types in their name and then clicks the button to submit the answer. What I want the computer to do, is on the button press it will read whats inside the text and the save it to a variable. Once it saves it, it will print it out.

The code below is bad because it runs through the `if` statement immediately without the consulting of the button press.

There has to be a simpler solution. Also this may not be PEP 8 or whatever please be patient because I'm new.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
import sys
import time
import random
import threading
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")

window.title("GUI")

def start_screen():
    reset()
    start = tk.Label(window, text="start of game")
    start.place(x=110,y=20)
    play = Button(window, text= "play", command = start_game)
    play.place(x=110,y=50)
    helper = Button(window, text="help", command = help_screen)
    helper.place(x=110,y=70)

def stuff():
    global t
    t = True
    print(t)
    return t
 
def text_handling():
    global t
    t = False
    reset()#clears the screen
    label = Label(window, text='')
    question1= "what is your name?"
    label.pack()
    print_slow(label, question1, 40)#prints out letters slowly

    #here is the part I'm having problems with
    name = Entry(window)
    name.pack()
    but = Button(window, text="enter", command= stuff)
    
    but.pack()
    print(t)
    if t == True:
        myPlayer.name = name.get()
        print(myPlayer.name)
    

def start_game():
    reset()
    bt = tk.Button(window,text="Enter", bg="orange", command = 
    text_handling)

    bt.place(x=100,y=100)

start_screen()
```

Comment: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: how about You place that if statement in its own funciton?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, that's a good point, but I wouldn't know how to move the name into the function cause right now its just a local variable myPlayer.name = name.get()

Comment: well then the simplest is probably `global name`